# WPF Toolkit Datagrid with .Net 3.5 no sp1

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I've been trying to use the WPF toolkit in a WPF application that I'm deploying internally at my company, but the toolkit needs .Net 3.5 sp1. The only difference between sp0 and sp1 for the toolkit is the `MultiSelector` class that the `DataGrid` uses.

My question is, does anybody know of a workaround for this so sp1 isn't required? Is there a custom `MultiSelector` class that I could use?

I know the toolkit was started before sp1 but I'm not sure what kind of progress was made before the `MultiSelector` was added.

I've tried using `ILDasm` to get the IL code for the `MultiSelector` class and generate my own, but I haven't had any success as it implements features from internal parts of the `Selector` class in `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Any help on this matter would be great, and upgrading everybody to .Net 3.5 sp1 is currently not an option.

If anybody knows about another free `DataGrid` control that could be used in place of the WPF Toolkit, it would be appreciated as well.

Thanks,

-Noah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use a different MultiSelector, as the one in the toolkit has a hard reference to the type in the SP1 version of the framework.  Even if you did create your own MultiSelector for use, you would have to change the grid control to use yours, which would require decompiling it into source, modifying it, and then recompiling it, which beyond being a PITA, is probably a violation of the EULA as well.

As for a free data grid alternative, I would check out Xceeds DataGrid for WPF.  The Express edition is free:

http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html

Comment: Heh, I didn't even think about the EULA when changing the code, I'll have to give it a read